# How to delete files with err "Is a directory"?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, rm

Can you help? When I try to remove a file this happens:

```
yoong@DESKTOP-HFN4TO5:~$ mkdir yes

yoong@DESKTOP-HFN4TO5:~$ rm -f yes
rm: cannot remove 'yes': Is a directory
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this:

Assuming this directory is **not** empty, you have the ability to use the `rm` command like you had originally tried but it will require you to specify some options besides just `-f` (force).

```
$ rm -rf yes
```

The `-rf` options will be a recursive force. Take care when using the recursive force if you are using `sudo`.

If you want to remove an empty directory, you can use the `rmdir` command which removes an *empty* directory.

```
$ rmdir yes
```

or

```
$ rm -d yes
```

`-d` with the `rm` command specifies that you will be removing an *empty* directory.

This could help:
https://linuxize.com/post/rm-command-in-linux/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).